# VBA: Function to remove all special characters

Tags: vba, excel

I've done some searching for a solution to this and I've not been able to find something I can use directly.  Therefore, by trying to edit someone else's code for my own use, I've come to an issue.

I'm trying to use the line `RemoveSpecialChars("$C$1")` but I get an `Object required` error.

The function is as follows:

```
Function RemoveSpecialChars(ByVal mfr As Range)

    Const splChars As String = "!@#$%^&()/"
    Dim ch As Characters

    For Each ch In splChars
    mfr.Replace What:=ch, Replacement:="", LookAt:=xlPart, _
                SearchOrder:=xlByRows, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False, _
                ReplaceFormat:=False
    Next ch

End Function
```

This is a simple question, but **is "$C$1" not considered a range?**

Thanks for your help.

**Edit:** If I use `Function RemoveSpecialChars(mfr As Range)` (without `ByVal`), I then get a `Type mismatch` error.

This further leads me to believe that "$C$1" is not considered a range.

**Edit2:**

@sous2817

This is how I set up the string `mfr` to be used with your function.

```
Range("C1").FormulaR1C1 = mfr
```

This is how I attempt to apply it.

```
Range("C1").FormulaR1C1 = RemoveSpecialChars(C1)
```

Comment: "C$1" Is indeed not a range. It is a string in which you wrote 4 characters. In the same way, "4" is not a numeric value but a string (though VBA treats them similarly sometimes) and "ThisWorkbook" is not a workbook, but a string in which you wrote "ThisWorkbook".

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Don't pass the "$".  This worked for me:

```
=RemoveSpecialChars(C1)
```

Now this opens up other issues in that the code son't do what you want it to do as you can only iterate over collections and arrays, not strings.

Try this (which I'm sure can be cleaned up, but hopefully will get you going the right direction):

```
Function RemoveSpecialChars(ByVal mfr As Range)

    Dim splChars As String
    Dim ch As Variant
    Dim splCharArray() As String

    splChars = "! @ # $ % ^ & () /"

    splCharArray = Split(splChars, " ")


    For Each ch In splCharArray
    mfr.Replace What:=ch, Replacement:="", LookAt:=xlPart, _
                SearchOrder:=xlByRows, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False, _
                ReplaceFormat:=False
    Next ch
    RemoveSpecialChars = mfr

End Function
```

IF you're calling this from a sub, you should qualify your range reference, here is one way:

```
Sub test()

    Dim test As String

    test = RemoveSpecialChars(Sheet1.Range("C1"))

    Debug.Print test

End Sub
```

due to question update.  Here is ANOTHER way to populate the formula:

```
Sub test2()
    Sheet1.Range("D1").Formula = "=RemoveSpecialChars(C1)"
End Sub
```

Ok, last edit.  If you want to preserve the string and create one with special characters removed, you should take a slightly different approach.  Here is one way:

```
Function RemoveSpecialChars(mfr As Range)

    Dim splChars As String
    Dim ch As Variant
    Dim splCharArray() As String
    Dim newString As String

    newString = mfr.Value

    splChars = "! @ # $ % ^ & () /"

    splCharArray = Split(splChars, " ")


    For Each ch In splCharArray
        newString = Replace(newString, ch, "")
    Next ch

    RemoveSpecialChars = newString

End Function
```

Comment: Ah the bug in the function makes sense now. use this answer :)

Comment: I think I'm missing something really easy here.  When applying this function, I'm trying to use the line `mfr = RemoveSpecialChars("C1")` and I'm getting a `Type mismatch`.  What am I missing?

Comment: it's not that you're missing anything...you're adding too much :)  Take the surrounding quotes away from the range, like this:  =RemoveSpecialChars(C1)

Comment: are you calling this from VBA or a worksheet?  I don't know why, but I assumed you were calling it from a worksheet....

Comment: Updated my question (at)you

Comment: @Tawm please see my test2() sub I just edited in.  If that doesn't get you close, we should move this to chat to further debug

Comment: Oooooooookay I got it working, I believe.  I'm now using the line `mfr = RemoveSpecialChars(Range("C1"))` and it seems to have done what I need.  Thank you very much!  I thought I had already tried that, but I suppose not.  Thank you very much for your help.

Answer (score 1):

This will probably be slower, but you can do it this way using the Ascii numerals.  You can also loop the string this way if you don't want to use replace:

```
Public Function AlphaNumericOnly(strSource As String) As String
    Dim i As Integer
    Dim strResult As String

    For i = 1 To Len(strSource)
        Select Case Asc(Mid(strSource, i, 1))
            Case 48 To 57, 65 To 90, 97 To 122: 'include 32 if you want to include space
                strResult = strResult & Mid(strSource, i, 1)
        End Select
    Next
    AlphaNumericOnly = strResult
End Function
```

Answer (score 0):

"$C$1" is not a range it is a string

try

```
RemoveSpecialChars(range("$C$1"))
```

ok didnt like above: lack of testing on my part. the below works but you come into another bug in the function of which I am not sure

```
Set Rng = Range("$C$1")
RemoveSpecialChars (Rng)
```

Comment: Lack of testing on my part the 2nd code above works but I am not sure what the next bug means